# dynamically displaying json data as a table when the structure/field names of the json data is not provided

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, json

In my application I will receive data in json format and I would like to display the data in tabular form in web browser.Please note that I will not be aware of the structure/field names of the data I receive.My requirement is to dynamically construct an table for any json object I receive.How will I achieve it using angularjs?Is there any other javascript library/framework like jquery/dojo that can help me achieve the said functionality?

Comment: You should check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180382/convert-json-data-to-a-html-table?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: Thank you Parth,I got a fair idea to start off with my requrement.I am initially looking at accepting a json data(where the details are unknown) and convert to an html table using javascript without using any js library or framework.

Answer (score 1):

While it's outside of the scope of an SO answer to write the code, I can at least give you the basics here:

**In your Controller: create column meta-data**

Loop through 1 or more objects and create your own metadata (I think XLS and MSAccess loop through the first 10-20 rows of csv data to get a basic set of fields.  maybe do that).

```
$scope.rows = /// Get your data ... a json array of objects, I assume.
$scope.columns = getColumnsFromRows($scope.rows);

function getColumnsFromRows(rows) {
   var cols = [];
   if(rows==undefined || rows.length==0) { return cols; }
   var sampleRow = rows[0];
   for (var key in sampleRow) {
      if (sampleRow.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
         // I would add some datatype checking here.  At least make sure
         // we aren't looking at an array or a sub-object.
         // Maybe turn a key like "firstName" into "First Name" for label 
         cols.push({label: key, fieldNm: key});
      }
   }
   return cols;
}
```

**In your view: ng-repeat through rows/columns**

The easiest thing to do would be to use ng-repeat to loop through rows/columns.

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
   <table>
      <thead>
         <tr><th ng-repeat="col in columns">{{col.label}}</th></tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <tr ng-repeat="row in rows">
            <td ng-repeat="col in columns">{{row[col.fieldNm}}]</td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
</div>
```

So, pretty simple.  Now, your entire table is controlled by your controller.  Add filters there, add sorting there, etc.

Fair warning, this is just example code.  As you get deeper, make sure to [take a deeper look at ng-repeat performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21397046/nested-ng-repeat-performance).  The bigger your dataset, the slower your page will run (ng-repeat creates it's own scope for every "cell" in your table).  That's why most people turn to libraries or directives to accomplish this task.

But, you're a smart guy.  You've got rep on stack.  You probably have a good reason for asking this question.  So, no preaching.  Good luck with the project!

Comment: Thank you bri,you gave me a fair idea of how to go about it.I am initially trying to just use javascript to convert the json data to an html table.Once that is done I will plan on using angular js to achieve the same.