# How can I use another for loop to print ID, Name or Type instead of bird.ID or bird.Name in Angular 7?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have data with variable numbers of columns. When I have a fixed column, I can show the data in table. But when I don't know all the column's names, then how can I show all the data in a table?

I am using angular 7.

```
  birds =
         [{
            "ID": "001",
            "Name": "Eurasian Collared-Dove",
            "Type": "Dove"          
        },
        {
            "ID": "002",
            "Name": "Bald Eagle",
            "Type": "Hawk"         
        },
        {
            "ID": "003",
            "Name": "Cooper's Hawk",
            "Type": "Hawk"            
        }];
```

Code:

```
                   <table *ngIf="birds">
                        <!-- ADD HEADERS -->
                        <tr>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>Name of Bird</th>
                            <th>Type of Bird</th>
                        </tr>

                        <!-- BIND ARRAY TO TABLE -->
                        <tr *ngFor="let bird of birds">
                            <td>{{bird.ID}}</td>
                            <td>{{bird.Name}}</td>
                            <td>{{bird.Type}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
```

The output should be a table based on the data.

Comment: Take a look at the first answer of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34765566/dynamically-displaying-json-data-as-a-table-when-the-structure-field-names-of-th

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get the keys from the object as
 `arr = Object.keys(birds[0])`
, store these values on a variable that will be an array, then proceed to use an NgFor on the table headers,

```
<tr>
  <th *ngFor=" let a of arr"> {{a}} </th>
</tr>
<tr *ngFor="let bird of birds">
  <td *ngFor="let a of arr"> {{bird[a]}} //As Bryan suggested!
</tr>
```

Comment: You’re better off doing like bird[a] for performance reasons. Tables can get very long

Comment: titanic = {"PassengerId":{"0":892,"1":893,"2":894,"3":895},"Pclass":{"0":3,"1":3,"2":2,"3":3},"Name":{"0":"Kelly, Mr. James","1":"Wilkes, Mrs. James (Ellen Needs)","2":"Myles, Mr. Thomas Francis","3":"Wirz, Mr. Albert"},"Sex":{"0":"male","1":"female","2":"male","3":"male"},"Age":{"0":34.5,"1":47.0,"2":62.0,"3":27.0},"SibSp":{"0":0,"1":1,"2":0,"3":0},"Parch":{"0":0,"1":0,"2":0,"3":0},"Ticket":{"0":330911,"1":363272,"2":240276,"3":315154},"Fare":{"0":7.8292,"1":7.0,"2":9.6875,"3":8.6625},"Cabin":{"0":null,"1":null,"2":null,"3":null},"Embarked":{"0":"Q","1":"S","2":"Q","3":"S"}}

Comment: Hello, @RNMR, If the data comes in the format shown in the above comment how can i format the table in angular?

Comment: @BCSmith well, arr should now be Object.keys(titanic), cause these are the new keys, and since the structure is different, something like.

Comment: yes. that i know. But i can't print the values of each column. nothing is showing there.

Comment: Hello, @RNMR,  can you please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55615609/how-to-print-key-with-multiple-values-json-data-in-angular-table