# How to print key with multiple values JSON data in angular table?

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I have data which i will receive as a JSON format from server and I have to show it in a table. I am parsing the received data and trying to show in the table.

So far i am able to show only the keys as a table header but couldn't show the column values associated with each column.

```
data = {"PassengerId":{"0":892,"1":893,"2":894,"3":895},"Pclass":{"0":3,"1":3,"2":2,"3":3},"Name":{"0":"Kelly, Mr. James","1":"Wilkes, Mrs. James (Ellen Needs)","2":"Myles, Mr. Thomas Francis","3":"Wirz, Mr. Albert"},"Sex":{"0":"male","1":"female","2":"male","3":"male"},"Age":{"0":34.5,"1":47.0,"2":62.0,"3":27.0},"SibSp":{"0":0,"1":1,"2":0,"3":0},"Parch":{"0":0,"1":0,"2":0,"3":0},"Ticket":{"0":330911,"1":363272,"2":240276,"3":315154},"Fare":{"0":7.8292,"1":7.0,"2":9.6875,"3":8.6625},"Cabin":{"0":null,"1":null,"2":null,"3":null},"Embarked":{"0":"Q","1":"S","2":"Q","3":"S"}}
```

I have parsed the keys using below code:

```
datakeys = Object.keys(this.data);
```

When i tried to show these data into table i can see only the headers. I think I am writing the ng-repeat in wrong way.

```
                    <table *ngIf="data">
                        <!-- ADD HEADERS -->
                        <tr>
                            <th *ngFor=" let tk of datakeys"> {{tk}} </th>
                          </tr>
                          <!-- BIND ARRAY TO TABLE -->
                          <tr ng-repeat="(k, v) in data">                                                        
                              <td ng-repeat="(k, v) in v">{{v}}</td>                                
                        </tr>

                    </table>
```

The output should be a table where there will be column name and its values. For example:

```
PassengerId  #   Pclass  # .......
892                3     # .......
893                3     # .......
..................................
..................................
```