# AngularJs - ngRepeat takes a very long time to display data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm getting a 100 items per page for my application. For pagination, I'm using a custom solution which makes a new AJAX call for the next 100 items. The time taken to get the data is around 400ms. But it seems the display is taking time to render. I read the cause could be `ng-repeat`. I cannot use `track by` since I don't have a column that has all unique items. I also read in a couple of solutions that I can use `limit` but since I already use server side pagination, I don't need limit. How can I improve the render time in this case?

Comment: Share some code to check

Comment: How would I? It's just about `ng-repeat`'s performance.

Comment: Not all ng-repeats are slow. It depends on the data and item it's repeating. That's why wanted to look at the code

Comment: You should show some code : how do you use ng-repeat (any custom filters ?) ? how your data looks like ?

Comment: Sorry can't do! It has a lot of proprietary stuff in there! I just want to fix the general issue of `ng-repeat` being slow.

Answer (score 1):

100 items should **not** be a problem for `ng-repeat`, but that depends on how your page completely looks.

`ng-repeat` creates lot's of watches which make angular's dirty check (digest process) longer.

Usually, you use `ng-repeat` in order to show data and not to create inputs and therefore you don't really need a two way binding (A one way will be enough).

So [bindonce](https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce) is a nice library that can help cut the not-needed watches.

Instead of doing something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="person in Persons">
        <a ng-href="#/people/{{person.id}}"><img ng-src="{{person.imageUrl}}"></a>
        <a ng-href="#/people/{{person.id}}"><span ng-bind="person.name"></span></a>
        <p ng-class="{'cycled':person.generated}" ng-bind-html-unsafe="person.description"></p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

You should do something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li bindonce ng-repeat="person in Persons">
        <a bo-href="'#/people/' + person.id"><img bo-src="person.imageUrl"></a>
        <a bo-href="'#/people/' + person.id" bo-text="person.name"></a>
        <p bo-class="{'cycled':person.generated}" bo-html="person.description"></p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Will it work with my pagination solution? I have simply added 2 buttons at the bottom, which calls the same function as used to get first 100 items, but with a page number.

Comment: I have no idea what your pagination looks like. Bind once is good for showing data (and not inputs). Assuming you load 100 items and only want to show them to the user it's perfect. If you need to load 100 more in the next page then this will work as well since we are talking about a one way binding.

Comment: The initial 100 items are requested from the server by a function, say `getItems()`. I have added a button after the list which calls the same function, but with an additional page number parameter, such as `getItems(1)` etc. The same variable is used for the new 100 items as well, since assigning the new value removes the old values from my table and displays the new ones.

Comment: I'm using `angular-ui-router` for routing. How can I use `bo-href` for links?

Answer (score 0):

If you have dynamic data with large amount then look into following link...it may be help you lot.

> [Angular ng-class performance issue when too many elements in DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25481021/angular-ng-class-performance-issue-when-too-many-elements-in-dom)